# Jekyll markdown converter escaping tags

Tags: markdown, jekyll

EDIT: I answered my question--sort of--but the answer makes me angrier than the problem did. If the markdown file ends with a `\n` the converter works exactly as expected. If the markdown file ends with a letter or a period (or any other character, presumably), I get the issue. So far, my fix has been `content += "\n"` but I have no idea why that works. So the question still stands, I guess.

I have written a Jekyll converter that takes a series of footnotes out of a markdown document and appends them to the end of that same document as an `<ul>` with a series of `<li>` tags.

The converter works great, except that the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags are being escaped somewhere along the line and appear as regular text along with the rest of the document.

That is, I should get:

- Footnote 1
- Footnote 2

But instead I get:

<ul><li>Footnote1</li><li>Footnote2</li></ul>

So, I assume the markdown conversion happens *after* custom converters run and markdown is escaping the tags, but I don't actually know. Is a converter the appropriate place to do create the footnotes? If so, how can I ask markdown to leave my tags alone?

If it is relevant, the content is inserted via `{{ content }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
{::nomarkdown}
your code here
{:/nomarkdown}
```

or

Remove all indentation from your generated code.
If you have four space indentation, kramdown treat this like code.

Comment: saved my life, or atleast an entire day